# Different kind of IPs

Tags: networking, server, internet, ip, router

I'm trying to do port forwarding so that I could connect from AWS EC2 to my local ubuntu machine.

My local machine ubuntu is connected to wifi(Router).

So while trying to accomplish, came across so many IPs and got confused.

Here they are:

1) `ip route | grep default`  on my local ubuntu machine gives me `192.168.0.1` ... Is it router's local IP ..? Then what's public IP ..?

2) `curl ifconfig.me` gives me `103.100.85.25` .. Is it my machine's local IP ..?

3) Opened my router's login page, Where WAN IP address is `192.168.55.6` and `192.168.0.111` is mine LAN IP's address connected to my machine.

I'm confused to understand all these IPs, Can anyone please help me to understand what these IPs are how they are working together ..? That wil help me to go ahead...!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to setup your internet router for port address translation (or port forwarding)
For example, for SSH, il will be:
Forward TCP port n 22 to 192.168.0.111
You may also configure the Ubuntu firewall to accept inbound traffic for the corresponding port & protocol

```
                   +-----------------+
                   |                 |
  +----------------|-INTERNET--------|
  |                |                 |
  |                |                 |
  |                +-----------------+
  |
  |                +----------------+
  |  103.100.85.25 |                | 192.168.0.1
  +----------------@  Router        @-----------------+
                   |                |                 |
                   +----------------+                 |
                                                      |
                   +----------------+                 |
                   |                |192.168.0.111    |
                   |     PC         @-----------------+
                   |                |
                   +----------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

1) shows the local IP of your router, the *route* from your computer to the outside world.
2) shows your public IP accessible from the world
3) the second IP shows your computers local IP, the WAN IP I don't know of, you won't need it.

To connect to your local network from outside, you need to connect to the global IP. Routers usually deny (drop) incoming requests. So, you need to tell the router, to which local IP it should forward incoming traffic on which port. How to do this depends on your router.

Most public IP addresses will change, and you might want to use a dyndns service. Some routers can do this, or you can set up a dyndns client on your computer.

Note, that if you use port forwarding on your router, you expose your computer to the www and you should know what you're doing, have your software always up to date and use strong passwords or better public/private key if available.

Comment: Is it correct, Router assigns private IP to himself and device connected to it ..? And When ever device sends request to the internet,  request carried from device by its local ip (assigned by router) to router's local IP and then router's local IP to router's public IP and then requested server on internet ...Is it correct thinking ...?